# AngularJS 1.4.8 - ngOptions in a select - infinite $digest() loop when I programmatically set model before option is in ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I encountered this when migrating from 1.2.14 to 1.4.8.  This works fine in 1.2.14, but I get an infinite **$digest()** loop in 1.4.8.  Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/do77waht/1/) demonstrating the problem.  The Fiddle is a lot easier to look at than this post, but SO is making me include code

I have a `select` element that looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="opt.id as opt.label for opt in getOptions()">
```

My options are objects, like this:

```
$scope.options = [ { id: 1, label: 'one' }, { id: 2, label: 'two' } ];
```

The array of options I want to give the ngOptions directive depends on conditions; sometimes I just want to give it `$scope.options`, but sometimes I want to include another option.

```
$scope.getOptions = function() {
    if ($scope.showThirdOption)
        return [{ id: 3, label: 'three' }].concat($scope.options);
    else
        return $scope.options;
};
```

Now, if I programmatically set my model to 3:

```
...
$scope.selectedId = 3;
...
```

...Angular won't be upset, even though that option doesn't exist.  It just adds an `<option>` node to the `<select>` element: `<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>` and the selected value in the dropdown appears blank.

But if I then set my state s.t. my **getOptions()** returns that additional option:

```
...
$scope.selectedId = 3;
$scope.showThirdOption = true;
...
```

...I get an infinite **$digest()** loop.

[image: errors loop bad]

Is there a nice way of avoiding a problem like this?  Do you think it's a bug in Angular (it is technically a regression), or is this just... not a way I should be using ngOptions?

[**~~~ Again, I have a nice Fiddle for you to play around with!! ~~~**](http://jsfiddle.net/do77waht/1/)

Comment: Here's an example showing that this problem doesn't arise if your options are values instead of objects: [**http://jsfiddle.net/x15jccmj/3**](http://jsfiddle.net/x15jccmj/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you call function getOptions() in ng-options. Create new variable and assign value returned by this function, then use it in ng-options:

```
$scope.newOptions = $scope.getOptions();

ng-options="opt.id as opt.label for opt in newOptions"
```

Also don't forget to update newOptions on button click.

Then you'll have no infinite digest. 
See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbcjeuhb/